# Xcode Recieve notification only when app is active

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, push

I write in Objective-C. 
I'm using remote push up notification for app control. I don't want to disturb users with alerts and sounds when app is not active. What i need to do - if app is not active - do nothing when notification is recieved. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are palyload structure which you need to receive for your case:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

BTWL: you can not mention badge as well, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to send silent notifications.  A notification sent without an `aps` key is silent.  iOS will not play a sound, nor will it display a banner on the device.  Your app will still receive such notifications, if it's running, and can respond as it chooses.  If the app is in the background, it can display a local notification, or it can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

just add below code into your Appdelegate.m file

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if(state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        //app in active mode
        // add your code as you want to handle
    }
    else{
        // app is in terminated mode
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows alerts with sound when app is inactive.

Comment: You have to set **UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);** in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: It is possible to do with specific payload which I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than i thought. Just no alert and sound elements in array in section aps. 
No alert - nothing to show.
No sound - nothing to play.